# MULTI Debugger Stop on Throw/Break on Exception

Tags: debugging, exception, breakpoints

I am using the GHS MULTI Debugger to debug an integrity project for an embedded application. Does anyone know how to configure a stop on throw for this debugger like you can do in GDB? I want to have it break when an exception is thrown. (I know the majority of SO does not develop Integrity projects or use the MULTI debugger, but I thought I would throw this out there to see if any other Integrity developers might know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example let's assume your Integrity project is named Test.gpj.

Before compiling your code, edit your Test.int file in a text editor and change the "StartIt" value to false. This will prevent the executable from starting immediately when it is loaded.

Then in the simulator (or on the target), when you load your executable, start debugging it with the Test_as0 file.

In the Multi Command line, enter:

`e __throw`

Set a breakpoint on the beginning of this function (set the breakpoint to be an any task break point).

Repeat this also for the __rethrow function.

Now, when an unhandled exception occurs when your executable is running, it will hit one of these break points. You can then navigate the call stack and see where this exception is occurring. (There is an option in the Debugger GUI to navigate up and down the stack frames). Alternatively you can enter:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> will navigate up and down the stack frames to find where the exception was encountered.